# jQuery change image of a child div

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with a jquery script that i'm trying to do, the code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="box right">
    <div class="image">
           <img src="domainname/folder/folder/gear.png" alt="Teambuilding">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
            <span>Teambuilding</span>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery(".box").hover(
          function(){this.next().next().src = this.next().next().src.replace(".png","2.png");},
          function(){this.next().next().src = this.next().next().src.replace("2.png",".png");
     });
});
</script>
```

This is the error that I get in Chrome : `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'next'`.

I don't get it `.next()` shouldn't traverse the DOM to the next element?

Thanks

Comment: jquery next() - Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector. The key here is next sibling

Comment: Inside a jQuery event handler, `this` is not a jQuery object, it is the DOM element.  So replace `this.` with `$(this).` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search the children elements, use `find()`

```
$(this).find("img").attr("src", function() {
    return this.src.replace(".png","2.png");
});
```

`next()` searches the next sibling element, you need to find the children.

Comment: <code><script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery(".box").hover(
          function(){jQuery(this).find("img").src = jQuery(this).find("img").src.replace(".png","2.png");},
          function(){jQuery(this).find("img").src = jQuery(this).find("img").src.replace("2.png",".png");
     });
});
</script></code> i've changed with this and i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined "

Comment: @kGk13 -- I edited the code for replacing the source

Comment: jQuery(function(){
     jQuery(".box").hover(
          function(){jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", function(){
   return this.src.replace(".png","2.png")});},
     function(){jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", function(){
   return this.src.replace("2.png",".png")});}
);
});    i get this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" , maybe i'm to noob, anyway thanks for the help .. http://jsfiddle.net/RaHc3/ this should be more useful